# mongodb schema data type for a list of numbers (or an array of numbers without a specific size)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

what kind of schema data type should i use to define a list of numbers (or an array of numbers with changing size)
I tried :

```
{type : [Number]}
```

but i suspect it may cause problems as i try to insert a value to the array (with `$addToSet`) from nodejs nothing happens,although trying to do this from mongodb interactive shell works fine.. perhaps(most likely) it's a different problem but i would like to remove any doubts regarding the way i defined the schema.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `schema.key.push(number)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fieldName: [ { type: Number } ]
```